# how to do image segmentation using built in fcm function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I am new to matlab. Actually I have to do retinal blood vessels segmentation. I have used kmeans clustering for segmentation, but result is not satisfactory. Now I want to try out fuzzy c means clustering technique. However I am not able to find out how to use matlab built in function for this purpose. Please guide me about this. I have gone through the following page, but I am not able to understand how to apply all this to my image.

https://cn.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fcm.html
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A minimal working example:

```
% some sample rgb image
MyImage = imread('autumn.tif');
% display it
figure; imshow(MyImage)
% size of the image
sz = size(MyImage);
% reshape the image to column format (each color band into one column). I guess you
%also did this for the k-means. If not that's why you did get poor results.
ImageInColumnFormat = reshape(MyImage,[],sz(3));
% number of clusters you want
NumberOfClusters = 4;
% U shows how likely each pixel belongs to each cluster.
% double() is only necessary because the sample image is uint8 and fcm has trouble with that format. You may not have to do that.
[~,U] = fcm(double(ImageInColumnFormat),NumberOfClusters);
% Get for each pixel the most likely cluster
[~,Labels] = max(U,[],1);
% reshape it back into the image format
LabelsInImageFormat = reshape(Labels,sz(1),sz(2));
% show result
figure; imagesc(LabelsInImageFormat)
```

Comment: Moesinger My question may be dumb to you , but why are you using ~ . what is the purpose of using ~ here. while matlab documentation says "[centers,U] = fcm(data,Nc)". Also I am getting an error. Error using max
MAX with two matrices to compare and two output arguments is not supported.

Error in blood (line 18)
[~,Labels] = max(U,1);
 I know that this error is coming because max() accepts 1 input argument. How to solve this error here to get most likely cluster.

Comment: @sidraAleem `~` ignores a specific output of a function to avoid creating unused variables. In this situation this is done because we are only interested in `U` and don't need the cluster centres. See https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html About the `max()` error: My mistake, was a typo, thx pointing it out! fixed.